# How to store the API list and authorization key in the appsetting file

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am calling some API from ASP.NET Core MVC application and I hard coded the API inside the controller along with the authorization key. How can I move this API list and authorization key in the appsetting.json file, so I can change the configuration file later for production as well?

[image]

Comment: Please detail the version of .net core you are using.

Comment: Targeted version: <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your appsettings.json file, add api url's like below,

```
"AuthKey": "your_authorization_key",
"SomeApi": {
    "Clinical": "https://tsrvcis/...?format=json",
    "Demographic": "https://tsrvcis/...?format=json"
  }
```

And then in the code access it in your HomeController like,

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public JsonResult GetAPIData(string param)
    {
        var authKey = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthKey");
        var clinicalUrl = _configuration.GetSection("SomeApi:Clinical").Value;
    }
}
```